# What happened to the quick desktop button?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

In 10.10 in the task bar there was a button that minimized all windows. Now that there is no task bar (bummer) the button is gone (double bummer) anyone know how to get it back? The button or the taskbar.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a "Show Desktop" button to the launcher by following this  [guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/show-desktop-icon-for-ubuntu-unity.html).

Answer (score 7):

Use the <kbd>Super</kbd>+ <kbd>D</kbd> combination. Ik acts as the 'Show Desktop' in 10.10.  To restore your desktop hit the <kbd>Super</kbd>+ <kbd>D</kbd> again

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I'll actually use but DoR answered original question so I am giving answer to him. +1